Android back button closes the app instead of popping the current route
Using the new Navigator 2.0 API for navigation in my Flutter app, I have the following simple version of my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Router(
        routerDelegate: AppRouterDelegate(),
        backButtonDispatcher: RootBackButtonDispatcher(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key, required this.openFirstPage});

  final VoidCallback openFirstPage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Main page'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Welcome to main page!'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: openFirstPage,
              child: const Text('Go to first page'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstPage({super.key, required this.openSecondPage});

  final VoidCallback openSecondPage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('First page'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Welcome to first page!'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: openSecondPage,
              child: const Text('Go to second page'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second page'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Welcome to second page!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin {
  bool _showFirstPage = false;
  void showFirstPage() {
    _showFirstPage = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool _showSecondPage = false;
  void showSecondPage() {
    _showSecondPage = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        MaterialPage(
          key: const ValueKey('MainPage'),
          child: MainPage(openFirstPage: showFirstPage),
        ),
        if (_showFirstPage)
          MaterialPage(
            key: const ValueKey('FirstPage'),
            child: FirstPage(openSecondPage: showSecondPage),
          ),
        if (_showSecondPage)
          const MaterialPage(
            key: ValueKey('SecondPage'),
            child: SecondPage(),
          ),
      ],
      onDidRemovePage: (page) {
        if (_showSecondPage) {
          _showSecondPage = false;
          return;
        }
        if (_showFirstPage) _showFirstPage = false;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? get navigatorKey => GlobalKey();

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(configuration) async {
    // Do nothing
  }
}

When clicking on the back button in the AppBar, the pages are popped as expected (the current page is closed and the one below it is shown):
Second Page ---> pop ---
    |                  │
    |                  ↓
First Page        First Page ---> pop ---
    |                  |                │
    |                  |                ↓
Main Page          Main Page        Main Page

..., but when the Android back button is pressed/swiped, the whole app is closed instead of the current page.
Second Page ---> Android back btn pop ---
    |                                   │
    |                                   |
First Page                              |
    |                                   |
    |                                   ↓
Main Page                         App is closed

Here's an illustration:


I suspect that the app exits because _showFirstPage and _showSecondPage are reset to their default values, leading to the removal of their associated pages from the navigator.

@NguyễnMinhKhoa I wonder why it isn't the same for the AppBar back button pop!

After examining different parts of my code, it turned out the code for AppRouterDelegate was wrong! Here's the correct version:
class AppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<bool>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey();

  bool _showFirstPage = false;
  void showFirstPage() {
    _showFirstPage = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool _showSecondPage = false;
  void showSecondPage() {
    _showSecondPage = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        MaterialPage(
          key: const ValueKey('MainPage'),
          child: MainPage(openFirstPage: showFirstPage),
        ),
        if (_showFirstPage)
          MaterialPage(
            key: const ValueKey('FirstPage'),
            child: FirstPage(openSecondPage: showSecondPage),
          ),
        if (_showSecondPage)
          const MaterialPage(
            key: ValueKey('SecondPage'),
            child: SecondPage(),
          ),
      ],
      onDidRemovePage: (page) {
        if (_showSecondPage) {
          _showSecondPage = false;
          return;
        }
        if (_showFirstPage) _showFirstPage = false;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? get navigatorKey => _navigatorKey;

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(configuration) async {
    // Do nothing
  }
}

The problem with the previous version was the following:
@override
GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? get navigatorKey => GlobalKey();

In that version, whenever navigatorKey getter is accessed (internally by the Flutter code), it will return a new instance of GlobalKey resulting in losing the instance attached to the Navigator when first built.
In the current version:
@override
GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? get navigatorKey => _navigatorKey;

... navigatorKey always points to a persistent global key, _navigatorKey, which remains the same in all cases.

Just edit  android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
to  android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="false" in your Manifest file
check this  answer

In android 15 u have to set true to made some features

@NguyễnMinhKhoa Setting enableOnBackInvokedCallback to true or false didn't make any difference in my case. I found out that something was wrong with my code. I will post the solution as an answer to the question.
